# How Do I Make the Text Position be the Same in All the Browsers?

Tags: css, image, text, position

On the page, the horizontal position of the text is different depending on the browser. Here's the website: http://www.nyestateslawyer.com/, the text in question is the two phone numbers in the red box. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

---

### Here's the CSS:

```
<pre><code>
#phone_text_manhattan
{
z-index:100;
position:absolute;
color:white;
font-size:15px;
left:777px;
top:263px;
}

#phone_text_bkln
{
z-index:100;
position:absolute;
color:white;
font-size:15px;
left:985px;
top:263px;
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Why are you using images to show the contact info? Aside from the fact that it looks _awful,_ it harms both accessibility (for blind users) as well as SEO.

Comment: That's why I wanted to at least change the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that component in a div, and position it relative to that div.
That means `position:relative;`
Now up to top most do it same, and at root tag specify it based of browser window width and height. so that all alignment will be same.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: How!!!
you want me to code css for that web page you provided? In that link web page there is lot of problem with styling. Give a sample code problem with specified scenario, i will try my best for sure.

Comment: What problem with styling? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dipak for the hint. Changed the position to relative and placed the text inside its parent div. Works.